# How to ignore some word from string replace using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have string which contain 5 to 6 word and i would like to replace some word with highlighter style.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var str = "Micromax Samsung S3 Microsoft Galaxy S";
     var arr = ["Micro", "s"];
     arr.forEach(function(item) {
          str = str.replace(new RegExp(item.replace(/\+/g, "\\+"), "g"), '<span class="red">'+ item +'</span>');
     })
     $('#dvHtml').html(str);
});
```

But i am getting every s in the entire string including  but i don't want to replace .

**Can any body help me to exclude or ignore following items from replace**

1. `<span class="red">`
2. `</span>`

**Output should be**

Now this will replace **Micro** with `<span class="red">Micro</span>` and **s** with `<span class="red">s</span>`

***Following are output***
[image]

Comment: What is it displaying right now?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have updated my question with output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need change your regexp something like this

```
var str = "Micromax Samsung S3 Microsoft Galaxy S";
var arr = ["Micro", "s"];
var t = str.replace(new RegExp('\\b('+arr.join('|')+')',"gi"), '<span class="red">$1</span>');

$('#dvHtml').html(t);
```

in this

- `\b` - find in begin word
- `arr.join('|')` - return string like `a|b` - so find any of them
- `gi` - flag for `global` and `ignore case`

you can try it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JwD7b/)

Comment: You can't apply the same procedure to the string again... is that valid for the asker?

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado what you mean?

Comment: if you do `str = t` and then rerun the replace line, it breaks. Is it valid for the asker? Maybe it is

Comment: Or, if your initial `str = 'Micromax <span class="red"> X </span> dd'`, it also breaks

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado i don't change source string, only save result to another string

Comment: Here's another case. If initially `str = 'Micromax <span class="red"> X </span> dd'`, it breaks

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado i don't think its use case of OP :-)

Comment: Let's hope so. He says "Can any body help me to exclude or ignore following items from replace: `<span class="red">`", so it is a use case... but it seems he didn't test it. Let's hope he doesn't need it ;)

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado nope, it proplem was only for his method :-) he try apply regexp for every item successively

Answer (score 2):

Here you have another solution.

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}

function highlight(str, needle){      
      var parts = str.split(/<[/]?span.*?>/gi);
      for(var i=0; i<parts.length; i++){
          if(i%2 == 0){            
              parts[i] = parts[i].replace(new RegExp("("+escapeRegExp(needle)+")", 'gi'), '<span class="red">$1</span>');        
          }else{
              parts[i] = '<span class="red">'+ parts[i] +'</span>';                
          }
      }
      return parts.join('');    
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   var str = "Micromax Samsung S3 Microsoft Galaxy S";
   var arr = ["Micro", "S"];
   arr.forEach(function(item) {
        str = highlight(str, item);
   });
   console.log(str);
   $('#dvHtml').html(str);
});
```

The advantage of this one is that **you can reapply the highlight method** as many times as you want on the processed string.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/4ZK7W/2/

Also, you can have special characters in the string to search.
For example, `var arr = ["Micro", "Sam|"]` does not highlight "Sam", but highlights "Sam|" if it existed in the str .

Cheers, from La Paz Bolivia

Comment: Excellent...really i appreciate your effort and it is really help me to escape char or string form sentence. my vote +

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Here you have a highlight plugin that deals with that problem:

http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

Hope it helps. Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i can not use this library due to some reason. can you help me to improve my answer